# Ansible: Validation

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansible 2.3. my Hosts are rhel 7.  I have several playbooks, e.g. user creation, removal, disabling, & system harding.
I am trying to figure the best way to validate accounts were created, disabled, etc..
Are there any suggestions ?  Does ansible have any built in modules, etc.. I do see you can add Log_Path in the config file..  or, do I just grep the log files on each host, for users that were added, disabled, or removed ?

Answer (score 1):

Playbooks by themselves are intended to "validate" the desired state. Each task run is essentially an assertion that the system be configured in one small way, such as a given user existing. Continue with the next task. Ansible will abort early on error.

That said, often when debugging playbooks and modules you want verification that things actually happened. as modules vary in how much validation they do. A few ways to do that. Run in check mode to simulate a dry run of what it would change. Use an Ansible task logging system like ARA or Tower. Write your own verification scripts in your preferred language. Enable relevant logging (syslog, audit) on the managed hosts and review that. Dump Ansible's scripts it runs on the hosts by setting ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES=1.

All of these are not necessary to run a tested playbook. They are tools to gain confidence that a playbook will result in a certain state.

Answer (score 0):

`tasks` in `Ansible` *validate* themselves a bit in the sense that a task like:

```
- name: a simple task
  file:
    path: /foo
    state: directory
```

will check if the there is an directory `/foo` before creating it and returning `OK` if the directory is already present.

Assuming it is asked how to check what Ansible has done on a has I would recommend to take a look at the [Linux Kernel Audit framework](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Audit_framework). The `audit` daemon runs in the background and logs system changed to `/var/log/audit.log`

> The audit framework works by listening to the event reported by the kernel and logging them to a log file.

It makes sense here to use a tool different from Ansible itself as bugs, wrong configurations, etc in Ansible could not be reported by Ansible itself.

For utilizing `audit` you need to install an Kernel compiled with `CONFIG_AUDIT` enabled and start the `auditd` service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ansible-playbook to validate for instance configuration drift with command line arguments.

```
ansible-playbook --check --diff
```